# How to pass a variable from one function to another function

Tags: python, function

I am making python based Email broadcasting in which i have created entries like email, pass, there is  csv browse as well which will brose a Email_list_container file and a submit button which will call a send mail function to send bulk email along with attachment, problem is when browse is used to grab emails from csv it stores to a variable and then return to function but when I call this variable in send mail function is does not allow me to use it there. same with attachment function is is not coming in send mail function either.

i have tried Global

```
newvar = browse()
```

and calling new var but this calls whole function to pop-up again new window to open another file which does not make any sense.
help me guys.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as msg
import smtplib as smtp
import csv
from itertools import chain

#browse function which stores value from csv file
def browse():
    from itertools import chain
    file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open CSV file")
    with open(file_path) as csvfile:
        read = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in read:
            ini_list.append(row)
    flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(ini_list))
    rcvr_emails =list(flatten_list)
    # print(rcvr_emails)
    file_label = Label(window,text=file_path, border=0, bg='#BAE1E3',font="inter 10", fg="grey").place(x=330,y=230)
    recemail = rcvr_emails
 
#what i want is submit function to grab a variable from browse function as email list 

def submit():
    try:
        email = login_email.get()
        pass_word = login_pass.get()
        subject = email_subject.get()
        body = email_body.get()
        server = smtp.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(email,pass_word)
        massage = "subject:{}\n\n{}".format(subject,body)
        server.sendmail(email,recemail,massage)
        server.quit()
        msg.showinfo("Status","Mails have been sent to the Targatted Email's List.\nThank You for using our services.")
    
    except:
        msg.showwarning("ERROR","SMTP API could not login the credentials,\nPlease check Email & Password then try again.")
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code here to help us better understand the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just return `recemail` from `browse` function then pass it as argument to `submit` function:

```
 def browse():
        from itertools import chain
        file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open CSV file")
        with open(file_path) as csvfile:
            read = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in read:
                ini_list.append(row)
        flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(ini_list))
        rcvr_emails =list(flatten_list)
        # print(rcvr_emails)
        file_label = Label(window,text=file_path, border=0, bg='#BAE1E3',font="inter 10", fg="grey").place(x=330,y=230)
        recemail = rcvr_emails
        return recemail
def submit(email_list):
// your code
```

Then in your main program:

```
received_email = browse()

submit(received_email)
```

Or in one line:

```
submit(browse())
```